# How to remove slash from env variable?

Tags: batch-file

I want to name dir after branch name but branch name is always prefixed with

```
origin/
eg. origin/master, origin/core
```

My env variable is set something like this:

```
set BRANCH="origin/master"
```

so next if I try

```
mkdir %BRANCH%
```

command, the directory is named ***origin*** because slash is not acceptable in dir name. Setting of ***BRANCH*** var is made earlier, outside of part of my code.

I want to mkdir named with string after slash eg. if ***BRANCH*** is "origin/master" I want make dir which will be called ***master***

EDIT: I am not sure if it is even possible but I dont see other way to get unique dir name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `/` this way:

```
set "branch2=%BRANCH:/=%"
```

Now if you do an echo on branch2 the result is:

```
"originmaster"
```

**Note**: You should assign your BRANCH variable like

```
set "BRANCH=origin/master" instead of set BRANCH="origin/master".
```

Now, to get the keyword you want you can do something like:

```
for /f "delims=/ tokens=2" %i in ('echo^(%BRANCH%') do set "branch3=%i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Windows uses back slashes in file paths, there is some compatability with using the incorrect forward slashes.

```dos
FOR %%A IN ("%BRANCH%") DO IF NOT EXIST "%%~nxA\" MD "%~nxA"
```